# Android Sqlite search like %

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to search a record in Android SQLite whether the record exists in any other column "ITEM_NAME" or column "ITEM_CODE".

It never works.

```
mCursor = mDb.query(true, ITEM_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {ITEM_ID, ITEM_CODE,
                ITEM_NAME, ITEM_CPRICE, ITEM_UPRICE}, 
                ITEM_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'"
                + "OR" + ITEM_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'" , null,
                null, null, null, null);
```

But searching in one column works

```
mCursor = mDb.query(true, ITEM_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {ITEM_ID, ITEM_CODE,
                ITEM_NAME, ITEM_CPRICE, ITEM_UPRICE}, 
                ITEM_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'"
                null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query looks correct except the

```
   "OR"
```

Its should be

```
  " OR "
```

Make it like-

```
       mCursor = mDb.query(true, ITEM_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {ITEM_ID, ITEM_CODE,
            ITEM_NAME, ITEM_CPRICE, ITEM_UPRICE}, 
            ITEM_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'"
            + " OR " + ITEM_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'" , null,
            null, null, null, null);
```